# How to Achieve CardView with Gradient Border in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I am working on a project. There is a button with elevation and gradient border in the proejct. I added this code to achieve that.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ll">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_border"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_buy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_shopping_cart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_buy"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_buy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text="Buy Now"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_buy"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_buy"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_buy" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

bg_gradient_border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:endColor="#840DB4"
                android:startColor="#DCA7F2"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <corners android:radius="18dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

As you can see from the output, the stroke width at the corners is not same as the normal stroke width. It is looking either bigger or smaller. I tried setting different values to card corner radius and stroke radius in the `bg_gradient_border.xml`. How to achieve consistent stroke size across all devices?

Answer (score 0):

**Result:**

[image]**Create a Gradient Border Drawable:**

1. Changes are done in **gradient_border.xml** for radius :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item>
>         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
>             <gradient
>                 android:angle="180"
>                 android:endColor="#840DB4"
>                 android:startColor="#DCA7F2"
>                 android:type="linear" />
>         </shape>
>     </item>
>     <item
>         android:bottom="2dp"
>         android:left="2dp"
>         android:right="2dp"
>         android:top="2dp">
>         <shape android:shape="rectangle">
>             <solid android:color="#fff" />
>             <corners android:radius="12dp" />
>         </shape>
>     </item>
>
> </layer-list>
> ```

Gradient border with round corners radius kept same as  **app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"**

2. **Create Your CardView with the Gradient Border:**

Now, you can use the CardView in your layout XML and set the background attribute to the custom drawable you created earlier:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>     tools:context=".MainActivity">
>
>     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
>         android:id="@+id/cardView"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>         android:layout_width="100dp"
>         android:foreground="@drawable/gradient_border"
>         android:layout_height="60dp"
>         app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
>         app:cardElevation="0dp">
>
> </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

Make sure to add @drawable/gradient_border as **android:foreground** .

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable for the gradient border (gradient_border.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:endColor="#840DB4"
        android:startColor="#DCA7F2"
        android:type="linear" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

Use this gradient border in an inset drawable (bg_gradient_border.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_border"
    android:insetLeft="2dp"
    android:insetTop="2dp"
    android:insetRight="2dp"
    android:insetBottom="2dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
        <corners android:radius="18dp" />
    </shape>

</inset>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a consistent stroke size for the gradient border around your CardView on all devices, you can use a different approach. Instead of using a CardView with a background drawable, you can create a custom background for your ConstraintLayout and apply a stroke to it directly. Here's how you can do it:

1. Remove the android:background attribute from your ConstraintLayout.

   ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">
    <!-- ... your layout contents ... -->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```
2. Create a new XML drawable resource file (e.g., bg_gradient_border_custom.xml) to define your custom background with a gradient border and consistent stroke size:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Background color -->
    <item android:id="@+id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Gradient border -->
    <item android:id="@+id/border"
          android:bottom="2dp"
          android:left="2dp"
          android:right="2dp"
          android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" /> <!-- Transparent color -->
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp" <!-- Adjust the stroke width as needed -->
                android:color="#840DB4" />
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
   ```

In this drawable, we define a transparent color as the background and apply a stroke with the desired width and color around it.

3. Apply the bg_gradient_border_custom.xml as the background to your ConstraintLayout.

   ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_border_custom"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp">
    <!-- ... your layout contents ... -->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

With this approach, you have more control over the stroke width, and it should appear consistent across different devices. You can adjust the stroke width in the bg_gradient_border_custom.xml drawable as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:left="0.100000024dip" android:top="0.100000024dip" android:right="0.100000024dip" android:bottom="0.100000024dip" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:endColor="#840DB4"
                android:startColor="#DCA7F2"
                android:type="linear" />
            <stroke android:width="0.100000024dip" android:color="#00000000" />
            <corners android:radius="15.0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:left="0.0dip" android:top="0.0dip" android:right="0.0dip" android:bottom="0.0dip" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
            <stroke android:width="5.0dip" android:color="#00000000" />
            <corners android:radius="14.0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Result:
[image: result]